# Group Concat columns based on previous records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-concat

I am facing quite a difficult query in my next report. I have a few clues, but can't seem to wrap it up in the right query. I have tried using `Group_Concat` over a `Concat` of the numbers, but I don't get the desired result.

> Exchanging shares in **Full Ownership**, **Freehold** and **Usufruct** (Google Translated these terms)

1. Person **A** buys 100 shares, numbers 1 - 100 in Full Ownership
2. Person **A** sells Full Ownership (FO) of 20 shares, numbers 81 - 100
3. Person **A** buys Freehold (FH) of 20 shares, numbers 81 - 100
4. Person **B** buys Usufruct (US) of 20 shares, numbers 81 - 100
5. Person **A** buys Full Ownership (FO) of 100 shares, numbers 201 - 300

Situation after these transactions:

- Person **A**: 180 shares in Full Ownership, numbers 1 - 80 & numbers 201 - 300
- Person **A**: 20 shares in Freehold, numbers 81 - 100
- Person **B**: 20 shares in Usufruct, numbers 81 - 100

-- In the database these transactions will be stored as:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------+
| ID | Shareholder | Quantity  | IsPurchase | NumberFrom | NumberTill | Type |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------+
| 1  | Person A    | 100       | true       | 1          | 100        | FO   |
| 2  | Person A    | 20        | false      | 81         | 100        | FO   | 
| 3  | Person A    | 20        | true       | 81         | 100        | FH   | 
| 4  | Person B    | 20        | true       | 81         | 100        | US   | 
| 5  | Person A    | 100       | true       | 201        | 300        | FO   |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------+
```

--> The desired output of my query is the following:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Shareholder | Shares_FO | Shares_FH | Shares_US | Numbers_FO     | Numbers_FH | Numbers_Us |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| Person A    | 180       | 20        |           | '1,80;201,300' | '81,100'   |            |
| Person B    |           |           | 20        |                |            | '81,100'   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

What I have so far is everything except the share numbers. I use `CASE WHEN` on the `Type` column to `SUM` the shares into the columns FO, FH and US. When IsPurchase is false, i subtract the number of shares. So all of that is working. I'm only missing the last three columns.

Code snippet of the summing.

```
SELECT Shareholder,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'FO' THEN 
            CASE WHEN IsPurchase THEN Quantity ELSE -Quantity END
        END) AS Shares_FO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SRI_ID = 'FH' THEN 
            CASE WHEN IsPurchase THEN Quantity ELSE -Quantity END
        END) AS Shares_FH,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SRI_ID = 'US' THEN 
            CASE WHEN IsPurchase THEN Quantity ELSE -Quantity END
        END) AS Shares_US
```

Many thanks in advance!